# using aws cli is it possible to find what are the task running in a instance for ECS

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-ecs

Using aws cli is it possible to find the tasks running in a EC2 instance. I tried

```
aws ecs describe-container-instances --cluster my-prod --container-instances xxxxx-b5ab-4606-b8ec-xxxxxxxxx --region us-east-1 --profile mfa
```

but it did not return such information.

From the console browser under ECS Instance tab if I select under "Container Instance" I do get this information.

Comment: According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/describe-container-instances.html this command returns ```ec2InstanceId```

Comment: please see if this helps with the filter query on `list-container-instances`. reference - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cluster-query-language.html

something like `aws ecs list-container-instances --filter "ec2InstanceId in ['i-abcd1234', 'i-wxyx7890']"`

Answer (score 2):

you can try below script

- Get container instances
- Find task in each container Instances
- Grap instance from each container Instance
- Map task

```
#!/bin/bash
CLUSTER_NAME=my-cluster
CONTAINER_INSTANCE="$(aws ecs list-container-instances --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME --query 'containerInstanceArns[]' --output text)"
for container in $CONTAINER_INSTANCE; do
TASK=$(aws ecs list-tasks --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME --container-instance $container --query 'taskArns[]' --output text)
EC2_INSTANCE_ID=$(aws ecs describe-container-instances --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME --container-instances $container --region us-west-2 --query 'containerInstances[*].ec2InstanceId' --output text)
echo "**************************************"
echo "ECS TASK having ARN is $TASK"
echo "Running in EC2 instance having ID $EC2_INSTANCE_ID" 
done
```

[Find instance or instance ID of AWS ECS running TASK or Services](https://gist.github.com/Adiii717/fca85afe24f74a7259cf87ec058c00db)

You might be interested in this as well [get-ecsIP-for-ecs-service](https://gist.github.com/Adiii717/bbfdfaad6e2930bc1ee1003587bbb908)